# between vs inrange in data.table

Tags: r, data.table

In R's `data.table`, when should one choose between `%between%` and `%inrange%` for subsetting operations?  I've read the help page for `?between` and I'm still scratching my head as to the differences.

```
library(data.table)
X = data.table(a=1:5, b=6:10, c=c(5:1))


> X[b %between% c(7,9)]
   a b c
1: 2 7 4
2: 3 8 3
3: 4 9 2
> X[b %inrange% c(7,9)]
   a b c
1: 2 7 4
2: 3 8 3
3: 4 9 2
```

They look the same to me.  Could someone please explain why there exist both operations?

Comment: `X[b %inrange% list(lower = c(6,9), upper = c(7,10))]` -- Example of what Kristoferson said.

Comment: Compare `X[a %between% list(c, b)]` vs `X[a %inrange% list(c, b)]` and then read the docs again.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
> X
   a  b c
1: 1  6 5
2: 2  7 4
3: 3  8 3
4: 4  9 2
5: 5 10 1
```

Using the example in the comments:

```
> X[a %between% list(c, b)]
   a  b c
1: 3  8 3
2: 4  9 2
3: 5 10 1
> X[a %inrange% list(c, b)]
   a  b c
1: 1  6 5
2: 2  7 4
3: 3  8 3
4: 4  9 2
5: 5 10 1
```

It seems `between` looks at each row individually and checks to see if the value in a is such that c <= a <= b for that row.

`inrange` looks for the smallest scalar value in `c`, say `cmin` and the largest scalar value in `b`, `bmax`, forming a range `[cmin, bmax]`, and then checks to see if `a` lies in this range `[cmin, bmax]`, for each row in the `a` column.

Comment: This is incorrect -- `inrange` checks whether a value is in the union of ranges provided (in your example above `[cmin, bmax]` happens to be the union, but this need not be the case)

Comment: @sirallen, please provide an example o a different answer to the question so we can all understand. To just say this is incorrect it doesn't always happen, and then say nothing else is not really helpful.

Comment: `%inrange%` could have been called `%betweenany%`