# How to get the rows that one column is same and another column is similar between dataframe?

Tags: r

I have many large dataframes. I want to get the first column is same and second column's difference is less than 5000 between two dataframes.
such as:

```
>a
chr  pos
chr2 10000
chr2 20000
chr2 45000
chr2 60000
chr2 80000
chr2 100000

>b
chr  pos
chr2 10000
chr2 30000
chr2 40000
chr2 55000
chr2 80000
```

my expected result:

```
>c
chr  pos
chr2 10000
chr2 45000
chr2 60000
chr2 80000
```

I tried by this:

```
c<-data.frame(chr=0, pos=0)
for (i in 1:nrow(b)) {
    c1<-a[(a$chr %in% b[i, 1]) & abs(a$pos-b[i, 2])<=5000, ]
    c<-rbind(c, c1)
  }
c<-c[-1, ]
```

But it's too slow and bad effiency.
I hope to get a better way.
Thanks advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
library(data.table)
```

Create `a` and `b`

```
a <- fread("
chr  pos
chr2 10000
chr2 20000
chr2 45000
chr2 60000
chr2 80000
chr2 100000
", data.table = F)

b <- fread("
chr  pos
chr2 10000
chr2 30000
chr2 40000
chr2 55000
chr2 80000
", data.table = F)

setDT(a)
setDT(b)
```

**@Jaap method, no extra columns needed**

```
a[pos %inrange% b[, .(low = pos - 5000, high = pos + 5000)] & match(chr, b$chr)]
#     chr   pos
# 1: chr2 10000
# 2: chr2 45000
# 3: chr2 60000
# 4: chr2 80000
```

**Join method, requiring extra columns to be added (same output)**

Add bounds for considering `pos` "similar"

```
a[, `:=`(low = pos - 5000, high = pos + 5000)]
```

Join `b` with `a` according to these bounds.

```
b[a, .(chr, pos), on = .(pos >= low, pos <= high, chr = chr), nomatch = 0]
```

**SQL method, no extra columns needed (same output)**

```
library(sqldf)

sqldf("
select  a.*
from    a
        inner join b 
          on  a.chr = b.chr
              and b.pos between a.pos - 5000 and a.pos + 5000
")
```

Comment: Another possibility with `data.table`: `a[pos %inrange% b[, .(low = pos - 5000, high = pos + 5000)] & match(chr, b$chr)]`

Comment: @Jaap You're right about the `sqldf` output, I've fixed that now. And yeah, that  looks like a better `data.table` option. Feel free to add as an answer.

Comment: Not sure whether it is actually better. Feel free to include it, it is heavily inspired on a [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44473835/2204410) I posted.